# Add bullet points to description lists

Tags: lists, itemize, description

I'd like to add a bullet point to `description` lists.

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Term] Description
\end{description}
```

Basically what I want looks like the following, when rendered:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{Term} Description
\end{itemize}
```

Using the itemize  *hack* does not feel right. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\Item\item
\newcommand\SpecialItem{\renewcommand\item[1][]{\Item[\textbullet~\bfseries##1]}}
\renewcommand\enddescription{\endlist\global\let\item\Item}
\begin{document}
\SpecialItem
\begin{description}
  \item[Text] more text
  \item[and some] more text
  \item[] empty
\end{description}

\begin{description}
  \item[Text] more text
  \item[and some] more text
  \item[] empty
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

without setting `\SpecialItem` it will be a default list

Comment: This works! (bullet point is a bit smaller than the bullet point of itemize, but that's no big deal). Can I somehow wrap this in a single command, so I could do this selectively for some description lists?

Comment: @knittl: see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert: If you move `\SpecialItem` to be after `\begin{description}`, then the `renewcommand\enddescription{}` is not needed.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I know, but I prefer the other way

Comment: @Herbert: I guess your way is safer in that `\SpecialItem` can be invoked both from within the `description` environment and from outside.

Comment: @Herbert I've used the above code but the `Text` come over the `more text` I don't know why?

Answer (score 9):

The `enumitem` package mentions the following solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\litem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1,\enspace}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
  \litem{Text} more text
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Obviously this is not much nicer than what you do already...

Answer (score 3):

Using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) one can simplify the matter

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}
  {\description[before=\let\makelabel\bulletbfseriesmakelabel]}
  {\enddescription}
\newcommand\bulletbfseriesdescriptionlabel[1]{\textmd{\textbullet}~\textbf{#1}}
```

In the optional argument to `\description` one can add other customizations.

A more complicated way, that ensures one always uses the original `enumitem` provided `\makelabel` is

```
\newcommand{\changemakelabel}{%
  \let\enumitemmakelabel\makelabel
  \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{%
    \enumitemmakelabel{\normalfont\textbullet~\textbf{##1}}%
  }%
}
```

and then

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}
  {\description[before=\changemakelabel]}
  {\enddescription}
```

---

A perhaps simpler technique is changing the `\descriptionlabel` command; here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\bulletdescriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont
  \textbullet\ %
  \bfseries #1}

\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[mydescription]
  {before=\let\makelabel\bulletdescriptionlabel}

\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
\item[title] test2
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

One might want to simply patch the current `\descriptionlabel` command in a more abstract way, instead of having to look up the definition of `\descriptionlabel`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bulletdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\patchcmd\bulletdescriptionlabel
  {#1}
  {{\normalfont\textbullet\ }#1}
  {}{}
```

that is, getting a copy of `\descriptionlabel` and modifying it so that it typesets `{\normalfont\textbullet\ }` before the argument (which is the optional argument to `\item`).

Comment: Why is the more complicated way required? And what is wrong with the first approach?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way which works with the paralist package, for example if you want a compact list (few vertical spaces). It is really a slight modification of egreg's answer.

```
\usepackage{paralist}

\newcommand{\bulletdescriptionlabel}[1]{%
\hspace\labelsep
\normalfont
\textbullet\ %
\bfseries #1}

\newenvironment{compactitemdesc}
{\begin{compactdesc}
  \let\makelabel\bulletdescriptionlabel
}
{\end{compactdesc}}
```

This works better than Herbert' method if you have sublists: if inside your new list type you have some other list then its items will work as usual. In Herbert's method (redefining \item) all \item command of sublists will be affected. This is avoided when using \makelabel etc. as suggested by egreg.