# How to create a list like description environment?

Tags: lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add bullet points to description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/add-bullet-points-to-description-lists)

I want to create a new environment, called `usecase` that will function like `description` environment:

```
\begin{usecase}
   \item[Request item] Item is requested
   \item[Response] System returns requested item
\end{usecase}
```

And I want it to look like a regular billeted list with italicized terms, the same as the result of this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \emph{Request item} Item is requested
  \item \emph{Response] System returns requested item
\end{enumerate}
```

However, I am not sure how to get to the argument of the `item`, e.g. "Request item".

Thanks

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but would it be possible to explain what is going on there?

Comment: @drozzy in Herbert's solution he creates a switch called `\SpecialItem` to turn on the formatting. He then changes the `description` environment so that it turns the switch off by default for the next occurrence.

Comment: Thanks @cmhughes! But I don't want to change `description` environment, but define a new one called `usecase` to use alongside it.

Comment: I've added an answer there, that you can possibly adapt for your need. If none of those answers helps, please tell so.