# enumitem: newlist with description and bullet

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I've seen quite a few questions here on how to use `enumitem` with descriptions and bullets. I couldn't however find a solution where they created a `newlist` and that's where I have my problem:

I defined in the preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{codescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[codescription]{label=\textbullet}
```

And then in the document

```
\begin{codescription}
\item[title] test2
\end{codescription}
```

But even this small example (I was actually trying to set the font of the description element to a monospaced font) doesn't work. Did I get something completely wrong?

Comment: I should mention that it works if I don't use `description`, but `itemize` in the preamble part. But why? The documentation doesn't say anything about `description` being different than `itemize`, I think.

Comment: I found a solution how to do what I want (see [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/add-bullet-points-to-description-lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/add-bullet-points-to-description-lists), but to be honest I don't know why the code above does not work.

Comment: The key `label` isn't meaningful in `description`. I'm going to add a different solution to my answer to the duplicate question. Do you agree that this one can be closed?