# Description list looking like a glossaries list

Tags: lists, description

Is there a package or something that allows me to create a `list` (like `description`) that looks like a glossaries list, where the descriptions are indented the same length? Like it is if the `glossary-superragged` style is used in the `glossaries` package.

I know this could be achieved by creating a two column table, but I think that is cumbersome.

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/add-bullet-points-to-description-lists) describes how to do such a `description` list with or without bullets, but it doesn't say if it is possible to get the right "column" indented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glossary-superragged` style reserves `0.6\hsize` for the description text.  Using `enumitem` we can set the label width to `0.4\hsize` and indent the description this far, as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bulletdescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel
\patchcmd\bulletdescriptionlabel
  {#1}
  {{\normalfont\textbullet\ }#1\hfil}
  {}{}

\newlist{mydescription}{description}{1}
\setlist[mydescription]
  {before=\let\makelabel\bulletdescriptionlabel,leftmargin=0.4\hsize,labelindent=0em,itemindent=!,labelwidth=!}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydescription}
\item[First heading] A description text that is long enough to
  spread on to the next line, and saying absolutely nothing.
\item[Second heading] A description text that is long enough to
  spread on to the next line, and saying absolutely nothing.
\item[Third rather longer heading] A description text that is long enough to
  spread on to the next line, and saying absolutely nothing.
\end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

This builds on @egreg's last solution in the question you link to (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60282/15925).  A final `\hfil` has been added to the labels to make them left-aligned.  The main indentation is acheived by setting `leftmarigin` to `0.4\hsize` and `labelindent` to zero.  The remaining parameters are computed by `enumitem` via the `!` options, so that `labelwidth+labelsep` equals our `leftmargin`.

Comment: I get a "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line .." warning each time I use this. Can that be avoided?

Comment: The code above produces not such warning for me.  Check first that you are using the latest versions of the packages.  Otherwise, perhaps you should post a separate question with your sample code.