# Adding bullet points

Tags: lists, itemize, description

I'd like to add bullet points to the Lorem Ipsum descriptions found in here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/586c557e4fa3ca7871c371cb

I've taken a look at similar questions asked here, but being a beginner, I can't seem to understand how to incorporate what is suggested here [Add bullet points to description lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57876/add-bullet-points-to-description-lists) into my example.

Any advice?

Comment: Where do you want to add bullet points? In your ShareLatex example there is already a bullet point list under Embedded Software Engineer. Is this not what you mean?